# Stop logo appearing on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, if-statement

I'm using the wpjobmanager plugin.

There's a field called 'company logo' that displays a default logo on every job. I'm trying to disable it and only show a logo when a user has specifically uploaded one.

I created this IF statement, but for some reason, the default logo is not considered empty so it continues to display it. I've tried null too and get the same result.

```
$is_logo = get_post($post->ID, '_company_logo', true); 
if (!empty($is_logo)) { 
the_company_logo();
}
```

Could someone point me in the right direction here? I'm at a loss.

Thanks

Comment: It returns true because your code sees the placeholder image as an image. You're probably better off checking the URL of the image and hiding it with CSS or JS

Comment: Thanks David. I fear that's the only option left. I just hate the code being generated in the first place.

Comment: It's been years since i worked with WP Job Manager but maybe you can set a transparent 1x1 gif image as the default logo, not ideal but an easy workaround. Otherwise I'd just check the image URL and hide it with CSS using a partial match selector e.g img[src^=your-placeholder-image]{display: none}. If you want to do it at the PHP level then you might need to hook into the action and change it to your needs.

Comment: I looked at the [docs](https://wpjobmanager.com/document/template-tags/) and you can pass a second argument for `the_company_logo()` that defines the default image, did you try passing `null` here? `get_the_company_logo('thumbnail', null)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code for get_the_company_logo which returns empty string if not set.

```
/**
 * Gets the company logo.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 * @param int|WP_Post $post (default: null).
 * @param string      $size
 * @return string Image SRC.
 */
function get_the_company_logo( $post = null, $size = 'thumbnail' ) {
    $post = get_post( $post );

    if ( has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ) ) {
        $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), $size );
        return $src ? $src[0] : '';
    } elseif ( ! empty( $post->_company_logo ) ) {
        // Before 1.24.0, logo URLs were stored in post meta.
        return apply_filters( 'the_company_logo', $post->_company_logo, $post );
    }

    return '';
}
```

So if you did

```
if (!empty(get_the_company_logo($post->ID)){
   the_company_logo();
}
```

This would seem like it should work.  I am not using this plugin, so I can't really test this.

Comment: Thanks Howard, but get_post_meta wasn't returning anything when I was testing it, so I used get_post.

Comment: I don't really know anything about this plugin you're using, but it would make more sense that it's using post meta and not get post.

Comment: @michael74 I've looked at the project on github and updated my answer.  Let me know if that is what you're after.   Also... for whatever it's worth.  `_company_logo` appears to be `user_meta`

Answer (score 0):

Try this `the_company_logo()` function:

```
if(!empty(the_company_logo())) {
  get_the_company_logo()
}
```

I read this function here -> https://wpjobmanager.com/document/template-tags/.

Say me if you need some help.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately that didn't work. 

I think the problem is the company logo field uses a stock image by default, so it will never be considered empty. 

I need to prevent that field from getting a value in the first place.

Comment: You tried `the_company_logo($default = null)`. Another option is do a `echo` to show the logo url path and set the value like `if( the_company_logo() == 'logo_url'){ get_the_company_logo() }`, change 'logo_url' with the value get from `echo the_company_logo()` .

Comment: Thanks but that didn't work. Maybe I need to get the url like you suggested. I'll give that a try